# How to limit inbound SMB bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, smb, windows-server, qos

Prologue: This is not a duplicate question. There are many questions and answers about that subject, but I haven't found a single one which deals with *inbound* traffic and provides a reasonable answer. Having said this:

I have a Windows 2019 server which acts mainly as file server, providing data to clients via normal Windows shares (SMB). I have installed an SSH server there as well. In regular intervals (e.g. 5 minutes), scripts running on other machines log into that server via SSH to perform checks and administrative tasks.

When I copy very large files (e.g. 50 GB) to a share on that server (that is, via SMB), the scripts from the other machines often fail because connecting via SSH times out. The reason turned out to be that the SMB traffic takes up the server's whole network bandwidth, leaving nothing for other network connections.

So I'd like to limit the ***inbound*** SMB traffic rate on that server. As said above, I have found some good articles on how to limit the *outbound* traffic rate (e.g. http://woshub.com/limit-network-file-transfer-speed-windows/ is a nice summary of the easier methods), but this does not help here.

The only hint I could find regarding the inbound traffic rate was the "Advanced QoS Settings" of "Policy-based QoS", then "Specify the inbound TCP throughput level". This is not the solution to my problem, because a) it applies to all TCP traffic (whereas I want only inbound SMB traffic restricted), and b) it only tunes one parameter of the network stack (receive window size if I remember correctly), and I don't know the relationship between that parameter and the maximum traffic rate.

All Powershell commands I came across also related only to outbound traffic.

Could anybody tell give me a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that Windows has traffic shaping only for outbound connection or for inbound TCP
(but not SMB).

You will need to do the QoS traffic shaping in the router, which might require
getting a suitably advanced router.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Using a router would require some effort, because all of this happens on the internal network. Actually, the server is running in a VM (QEMU/KVM) on a Linux host; perhaps I can make use of that (although I really don't want to change the bridged network I have setup on the host). Another option would be trying to find out whether there is third-party software which can do what I want directly in Windows.

Comment: Even in the LAN, the traffic between computers passes through the router.

Comment: Thank you very much again, but unless I have a wrong definition of the term router, that isn't the case here. I have multiple PCs and servers which are connected by a non-managed layer 2 switch. The traffic in question is sent by one of the PCs, reaches the switch (which operates with store-and-forward), leaves the switch and reaches the server. That's all to it.

Comment: True, a non-managed switch doesn't help (unless replaced).

Comment: I am giving the answer to you because you have confirmed that Windows can't do it. I won't place a managed switch in front of that server, though - I will solve the problem using Linux's traffic shaping capabilities applied to the virtual network interface of that VM.

Comment: You can also do this with a policer on a switch hooked to the server. Not as elegant as a shaper, but also much cheaper than a router that can shape gigabit bandwidth.